# Delete and copy all files using linux command from Node.js

Tags: node.js

I was trying `spawn` command of Node.js.

I tried to simulate the bellow two command in Node.js

```sh
rm -rf *
cp ../dir1/* ./
```

My Node.js code is bellow

```js
spawn('rm', ['-rf', '*'], {cwd: '...'});
spawn('cp', ['./dir1/*', './'], {cwd: '...'});
```

It's not working. Though I'm not getting any error.

My question is - Am I missing something? or it's blocked for any security reason ? or is there any workaround there ?

[image]

Output: the all files in the directory (because of the `ls` command).

EDIT:

```js
const PUBLIC_HTML_PATH = '....';

async function clearFBPublicFolder() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const deleteCommand = spawn('rm', ['-rf', '*'], { cwd: PUBLIC_HTML_PATH });
        console.log('Removing files from', PUBLIC_HTML_PATH);
        deleteCommand.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
        deleteCommand.stderr.pipe(process.stdout);
        deleteCommand.on('error', (err) => {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
        });
        deleteCommand.on('close', resolve);
        deleteCommand.on('exit', function(code) {
            console.log('Removing files: exit code (spawn)', code);
        });
    });
}

async function main() {
    try {
        await clearFBPublicFolder();
        spawnSync('ls', { cwd: PUBLIC_HTML_PATH }).output.map((o) => console.log(o ? o.toString() : null));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

main();
```

*One Solution I can find that write shell script and then run it as part of node child process*

Comment: did you required `child_process` module?

Comment: Since you're doing this from within Node.js, is there any reason why you wouldn't use `fs` instead?  Spawning a shell command for this seems sketchy.

Comment: @Brad Fs module is great but does work well if you want to bulk delete or copy...

Comment: @RitwickDey Why not?  Loops exist.  Also, have you seen this module?  https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra

Comment: @Brad , yaa. i don't need fs-extra... I can write a recursive function. i just want to know,...

Comment: @RitwickDey I try your code, but it seems to work: https://repl.it/repls/AcidicBlankTree

Comment: @RitwickDey Just one final word of caution... your application isn't going to work everywhere.  You're making a lot of assumptions about the platform.

Comment: @Brad I don't need Windows Support. It's a custom Build & deploy Setup. Btw this can't be an answer.

Comment: One Solution I can find that write shell script and then run it as part of node child process

Answer (score 1):

After 2-3hr wasting of my time. I found that if I change `spawn` to `exec` (imported  from same package - 'child_process'), it working perfectly fine.

e.g:

```
exec('rm -rf *', {cwd: '...'});
exec('cp ./dir1/* ./', {cwd: '...'});
```

I still don't know why it's not working for `spawn`. If anyone know the exact answer, feel free to add another answer.

Comment: It's not working for `spawn()` because `exec()` runs in the shell, and `spawn()` just spawns a child process.

Answer (score 0):

For `cp` command, try this:

```
spawnSync("cp", ['src dest'] , {
            cwd: 'src',
            encoding: 'utf8',
            shell: true
});
```

This works for me with NodeJS v18